# Testing WPF application with Coded UI

Tags: wpf, testing, coded-ui-tests

I have to test a WPF application using Coded UI and have edited the `CodedUITestBuilder.exe.config` file to increase the `MaxLevelsForItemContainer` level to 10 but the changes do not reflect in the TestBuilder itself.

Comment: you mean they are not saved to the file or they are not reflected when the test runs? if so how can you tell that they are not reflected?

Comment: For example, I have a control that is inside five other controllers but when I record the action with the Coded UI Test Builder, variable is only showing 3 even though I changed the MaxItemsLevelForContainer variable in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds the same as this [bug already raised with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783270/set-maxlevelsforitemcontainer-value-in-vs2012).

There, the user states

> I edited the MaxLevelsForItemContainer keys [...but] the CodedUIBuilder still uses the default MaxLevelsForItemContainer.

Microsoft answers:

> The behavior is expected per our design. MaxLevelsForItemContainer
>   config is applied only on Item containers such as ListBox, ComboBox
>   etc. The reason behind this is the items within it could be
>   potentially virtualized during playback, so the recorder needs to
>   capture the entire hierarchy during recording for it to de-virtualized
>   each level and play back properly. In this scenario, there are only
>   nested Groups (they do not have ItemContainerPattern support as to
>   speak in UIA world). So the config does not apply for over.
>
> The workaround over here is to handcode the test script to add all the
>   nested controls in the search hierarchy.